# Laravel verify locale in url is same as user's locale from database

Tags: php, laravel, locale, middleware

So in my `LocaleMiddleware` class (which is located in the `web` group of the middleware), I have the following:

```
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->user()->getLocale()); // This just fetches the locale from the database for the given user
    }
```

And then it just returns the next request. However, there is a slight issue for example when logging in. I need to use the `return redirect()->intended();` option. This poses a problem when I have for example the following route that I point to:

```
https://www.example.com/es/cervezas/dos
```

The English variant of this url would be:

```
https://www.example.com/en/beers/two
```

My routes look like this for example:

```
Route::name('user.')->prefix(app()->getLocale())->group(function () {
    Route::get(trans('routes.beers'), [BeersController::class, 'index'])->name('beers.index');
}
```

So in my routes I translate everything, and I also have slugs for each of my database models etc, which is why I always need to have the correct locale set but also I always need to have the correct locale in the url. If not I get not found exceptions when viewing specific model items or weird translations.

But one of the main problems is, when I go to the Spanish route for example (or any route for that matter in any language), after logging in, it will return the intended url/route, which will be the English one since `en` is the fallback locale.

So basically, what I was thinking is something along the lines of this, in my `LocaleMiddleware` class:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    app()->setLocale($request->user()->getLocale());

    // Check if the segment locale is the same as the user locale
    // IF NOT, redirect them

    if(request()->segment(1) !== $request->user()->getLang())
    {
        return redirect()->route(request()->route()->getName()); // Not sure what to do here, doing this just creates an endless loop because the locale somehow was not updated yet it seems
    }
}
```

Any ideas for a solution for this, in the `LocaleMiddleware` or anywhere else? Or am I going about this the wrong way entirely? Any pointers are appreciated!

**Edit:**

Now in my LoginController I have the following:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    app()->setlocale($user->getLocale());

    dd(app()->getLocale()); // This is the correct locale, `es` or `nl`

    dd(route('beers.index')); // This just always shows the English route
}
```

How come the `app()->getLocale()` shows the correct locale but the route is still always in the default locale? And of course, how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have access to the user in the login function before redirecting.
In many of my projects there is an admin panel and I use the same default login endpoint. During the login process I check where the user is an admin or not and decide where to redirect him.

Here's an example of the store function in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController in a laravel 8 project:

```
/**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN_HOME);
        }

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

So I believe that if you edit your redirection logic in the login controller it should work, because you have access the user, before you actually redirect him.

Comment: Makes sense, and sounds very logical. I will test some stuff out, haven't thought of that yet. However, that only would solve part of the problem. On rare occassions the url is showing `en` instead of the user locale as well. But I have not yet figured out why that is, so I will keep an eye on that. For now, your solution is a good answer to the question and I will accept it soon after some testing. Thanks!

Comment: Could you check the edit in my original question? Perhaps you have any tips for me there

Comment: @Hardist I see but it looks very strange.
I don't want to push you in the wrong direction and lose your time, but for multilingual sites I usually use this package: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

It's up to you to decide if you want to change your code to fit with the package and try some stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I figured out that the routes have already been mapped before the login controller so that is why they are not being translated there. I will take a look at that package, thanks again

Comment: Just an FYI, installed that package and tested it, everything works flawlessly, and it even improved some stuff for my site lol. I can also simply use my current routes so I only have minor changes to make. Great! :)